# Are there any potential issues with a Chabad tallis?

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, chabad, tallit-gadol

In an effort to reclaim some of my original minhagim pre-Chabad, I have started wearing a tallis for Shacharis, despite being unmarried.

I like [the distinct striping pattern](https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-78164/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/43/1495/Chabad_Tallis_worn__75496.1391344176.jpg?c=2) on a Chabad tallis, but I’m concerned that there may be issues I’m unaware of concerning [the extra shamash hole](https://www.tallit-shop.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Mishkan-Chabad-tzitzit1.jpg).

Is there any issue I should be aware of with the extra hole, and if so, what are they?

Comment: Well, the Beit Yosef says that an extra hole in the corner is yuharah (never learned this siman inside, so I don't know the reason)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt doesn't yuhara operate along a spectrum? What was once considered to be yuharah 500 years ago, is perhaps no longer considered such if it is widely practiced within a given community? Perhaps in such an environment, the contrary may actually be true - that being hoshesh for the opinion that it is yuharah itself constitutes yuharah! Just a thought..

Answer (score 1):

Well, some knowledge that I have off the top of my head is found in the Shulchan Aruch HaRav.
It states that you shouldn't have a 2nd hole on a Tallis Gadol (even if you have a 2nd hole on the Tzitzis) because it is considered pretentious. However, there is no fear of it being pretentious if the corners of the Tzitzis are worn under other clothes. Because it might seem pretentious to have 2 holes on both the Tzitzis and the Tallis Gadol. Which leads us to bring out that if the Tzitzis corners were under other clothes, it is okay to have a Tallis Gadol with 2 holes as well (Orach Chayim, Bach).
However, I might have to look into this Halacha more in order to give a better answer.

Comment: Also, if I am not mistaken, I believe I have seen Lubavitchers were 2-holed Talleisim before, so it seems to me that it wouldn't be against Halacha (in accordance to the Shulchan Aruch HaRav), or maybe it's possible that we just don't hold of that Halacha given by the Baal HaTanya and that is just his Shita.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Gershon and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @Gershon welcome! Your answer could be improved by providing the exact citation in the SA HaRav/OH Bakh. Or better yet pasting the relevant section of text here. Doing so allows others to more readily see and understand the grounds for your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The Mishna Berura indicates a priori whether in tying or after tying, they should hang in the kind side of the garment. With the two hole style you cannot drape the tzitzith on the long side at all.

And it may be less durable. Those two holes are like 1cm apart or less. Personally I find it spooky because it looks like snake eyes, so that might be a consideration as well, so if you have a personal aesthetic that clashes with that then that might be an issue for you.

Also it's not "on the wings of your garment" like how those who are careful swing the tzitziyoth to the lateral sides of the garment and not in the bottom edges of the garment.

Here is the Yalkut Yossef:

Y. Yossef. Din chutei hatzitzit #18 There are those who say that you have to be precise and hang the tsisit on the long side of the tallit and not on its short edge because we need the tsisis to be hanging on the wings of the tallit. But after the fact you don't have to make it an issue. But anyway to be careful that it's not hung diagonally.

YY bottom notes: SAOC 11:15. And the opinion of the MB is whether it's while tying them or whether it's afterwards, if they moved to the bottom he should bring them back. But all this is a priori but ex post facto you do not have to make it an issue. But in the Tehila l'David volume 1, page 11 he writes, that all the making an issue is during the tying, but afterwards one does not make an issue to move it back. And the MB adds that in any case be very careful that the tzitzith you do not hang diagonally on the corner, because it's a custom of the Karaites who do that as their practice, and if they're hanging it's a mitzva to move them back in their place. And see there in Beer Halakha which explains what is the long side of the tallit.

Ben Ish Hai Year 1 Noach #15: Rabbeinu Haim Vital testifies about the Arizal that on his tallit katan specifically there were two small holes close together resembling the nekuda Tzere on all four corners and his tzitzis would hang out from there going in and out on the same side of the garment. But the Ramak himself didn't do that and he or his son understood it's just because the Ari held on to that custom on his tallit katan from his Ashkenazi lands, therefore R' Chaim did not do it.

Lekh Lkha Year one #1: the braid you have to make it loops and loops each loop of three windings but first tie two knots close to the Kanaf [wing of the garment, not the bottom] and wind 7 windings and then tie another two knots..